# How to assign variables from text file in for loop of windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (servers.txt) do (
set server=%%i
echo server is %server%
)
```

Here it is unable to set value from text file to variable server.

Comment: When the for command is read, all the `%` variables are set to their value at the time, which makes it empty. `!` with delayed expansion waits til the line and commands around are read, then sets the value, allowing it to work in for loops and other odd scenarios.

Comment: try `call echo server is %%server%%`. By executing `echo server is %server%` outside of the block, you'll find the value is actually set properly to the last entry in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It is setting the value.  You are just not using it correctly.  You need to use Delayed Expansion when you are inside a code block.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (servers.txt) do (
    set server=%%i
    echo server is !server! 
)
```

Comment: Hi Sqashman,Thanks for your answer. I've another requiremnet that we want to use pushd \\!server!\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\EPMSystem11R1\OPatch and it is unable to navigate to that directory.

Comment: @navi27, update your question with all the code you are using.  You may think it is irrelevant but it helps to see in what context you are using the example to understand why it may or may not be working.  If the `%instance%` variable is inside the code block you also need to use delayed expansion for that as well.

Comment: @echo off

set instance=%username:~2%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%i in (servers.txt) do (

set server=%%i

echo server is !server!

pushd \\%%i\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\EPMSystem11R1\OPatch

echo current directory is %CD%

)

Comment: @navi27 I said update your question with all your code. I did not say to post it here in a comment.

Comment: Hi @Squashman, i figured out the problem. with in for loop it cannot execute more than 2 commands even after i included them in braces. I will post it as a new question and let you know.

Comment: Please follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095587/how-to-use-more-than-2-commands-in-windows-for-loop

Comment: @navi27 a FOR command most certainly execute more than one command inside parentheses.