# How to use more than 2 commands in windows for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
set instance=%username:~2%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (servers.txt) do (
set server=%%i
echo server is !server!
pushd \\%%i\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\EPMSystem11R1\OPatch

echo current directory is %CD%
)
```

Where servers.txt contains servers names.

Here if i include onlu pushd command inside for loop then it perfectly changing to remote directory but if multiple commands it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd \\%%i\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\EPMSystem11R1\OPatch

echo current directory is !CD!

POPD
```

If you continue `push`ing then eventually you'll run out of stack.

You need to use `!CD!` in place of `%CD%` because `%cd%` will be evaluated and replaced at parse time, showing misleading results. `!cd!` will show the run-time value.

You could also `CALL echo current directory is %%CD%%`

Comment: @Magoo....Thanks for answering.can u post me the command to pop out all opened UNC paths[remote directories].

Comment: if any command prior to popd fails, then popd is not gets executed. can you help me how can i solve this

Comment: @navi27 none of the commands in your code will fail which means you AGAIN are not showing us all your code.

Answer (score 0):

It can always occur that one of the servers to connect is not available currently in network. Command **PUSHD** exits with value `1` on error instead of `0` on success. This can be used to execute all other commands only if drive mapping to network share was really successful.

The code below demonstrates that:

```
@echo off
if not exist servers.txt goto :EOF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "instance=%username:~2%"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (servers.txt) do (
    echo Server is %%~i
    pushd "\\%%~i\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\EPMSystem11R1\OPatch" 2>nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo Current directory is !CD!
        rem Other commands.
        popd
    ) else (
        echo Not found: \\%%~i\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\EPMSystem11R1\OPatch
    )
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`